# Question in scattering in 1-dimension

Tags: quantum-mechanics, scattering

Let us consider the following quantum scattering problem in 1-dimensional space.
Let the Hamiltonian be
$$H=-\frac{d^2}{dx^2}+V(x),$$
where
$$V(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{cc}
                    0&\mbox{ if } x<0 \mbox{ or }x>1,\\
                    V_0&\mbox{ if }0<x<1
                    \end{array}
                    \right.$$
                    where $V_0>0$ is a constant.

Below I am using the notation of Newton's book "Scattering theory of waves and particles"

> Is it possible to write down explicitly the IN and OUT states, the M{\o}ller operators $\Omega^{(+)}, \Omega^{(-)}$ and the scattering operator $S=\Omega^{(+)\dagger}\Omega^{(-)}$?

An answer on physical level of rigor is sufficient for me, but a reference to a mathematically rigorous treatment would be of interest too.